# $\left(\frac{-\sqrt{2}}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{-2}}\right)^{2016}$

Tags: complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

This is a question I'm getting conflicting answers on.

**Method 1:**
Rationalize denominator of $−1/\sqrt{−2}$ to get $+(\sqrt{2}/2)i$, then square the whole thing, resulting in $-i$, then $(-i)^{1013}$, getting $-i$ as a final answer.

**Method 2:**
Rationalize like before to get in form $a + bi$, then convert to polar form, $r = 1$, so $(1(\cos\theta + i\sin\theta))^{2016}$, then $\theta$ is either $3\pi/4$ or $\pi/4$. Use De Moivre's to get $1(\cos(2016\theta) + i\sin(2016\theta))$. This results in $1 + 0i$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you squared the whole thing in method 1, you halved $2016$ to give $1013$, which is where the mistake is. It should be $1008$. This then does indeed give $1$, in agreement with method 2.

Comment: Ah, I feel like an idiot now, thank you for helping.

Comment: No problem :) ${}$

Answer (score 2):

$$\left(\frac{-\sqrt{2}}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{-2}}\right)^{2016}=\left(\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}i\right)^{2016}$$
then use the fact
$$\left(\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}i\right)^2=-i$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I have corrected the answer. Thanks